# Laravel-5.3 -Upload-savein database

Tags: laravel-5.3

How store path image with laravel 5.3 ?

```
    if(Input::hasFile('image')){

        $file= Input::file('image');
        $file->move(public_path().'/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
         $blog->title =$file->getClientOriginalName();

    }

    $blog->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it may be working.

```
$file= Input::file('image');
        if(!empty($file)){
        $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
         // please identify you upload location
         $request->file('image')->move( base_path() . '/public/uploads/', $filename );
     $insertdata = array('title'=>$filename);
     DB::table('table')->insert($insertdata );

}
```

Comment: Thanks but No   Working now ?